# how to make this div device responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have video in background, over background video two section is there one for sketch and other for text. When I am resizing the window text is overflowing.  I tried all the way i am stuck at this point. G

I have tried bootstrap and css(media, flex ) nothing is helping me out.
I just want when i am resizing the window or changing the device it adapt the screen resolution and does not overflow the content.

This is the big screen output

[image]

This is the small screen output

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap');
.process {
  position: absolute;
  width: 17rem;
  height: 5.9375rem;
  margin-left: -10%;
  margin-top: 17.5rem;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 5.9375rem;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.2625rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.8);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.dottedline {
  position: absolute;
  width: 811px;
  height: 500px;
  left: -642px;
  top: 70px;
  border-top-right-radius: 300px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
  border: 2px dotted #FFFFFF;
}

.ellips1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  left: 60px;
  top: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.ellips2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  left: 170px;
  top: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.ellips3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  left: 40px;
  top: 520px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.ellips1_txt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 342px;
  height: 95px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 20px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ellips2_txt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 285px;
  height: 107px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 15px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ellips3_txt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 421px;
  height: 130px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 10px;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.cti {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 27px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.desc {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.video_background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#myCarousel {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1.7px 5px gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">

<div class="Pipeline_count">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false" style="background: black">
    <div class="video_background">
      <video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted id="myvideo">
      <source src="./source/gradent_pink.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
     </video>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="desc_ col-sm-5">
        <span class="process">process</span>
        <span class="dottedline"></span>
        <span class="ellips1">
          <img src="./source/Ellipse_24.svg">
          <span class="ellips1_txt">Use recommendation Engines to plan flights and Ground Control Points</span>
        </span>
        <span class="ellips2">
          <img src="./source/Ellipse_23.svg"> 
          <span class="ellips2_txt">Robust Pipeline to process and efficiently merge large areas together</span>
        </span>
        <span class="ellips3">
          <img src="./source/Ellipse_22.svg"><span class="ellips3_txt">Deep learning analytics suite for urban / rural (identification of plots, roads etc) and precision agriculture (plant count and plant health)</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
      <div class="desc col-sm-5">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://sketchfab.com/models/93760d8297264eb184e5c3df52142d00/embed?autospin=0.2&amp;autostart=1&amp;preload=1&amp;transparent=1&amp;ui_controls=0&amp;ui_infos=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; vr" mozallowfullscreen="true"
            webkitallowfullscreen="true">
       </iframe>
        </div>
        <p class="cti">Click to Interact</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of @media only screen and (min-width:  ) and (max-width: ){ }
You can also use min-device.width: and max-device-width for mobile device responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of @media only screen and (min-width: ) and (max-width: ){ } You can also use min-device.width: and max-device-width for mobile device responsiveness.